# Connected to McDonalds WiFi, unable to reach internet

Tags: wireless-networking

My Toshiba Satellite A660 running Windows 7 is able to connect to public WiFi in general, but always trips up at McDonalds.  Same with my Toshiba Portege R930 running Windows 7.  I get to the landing page, click on Connect, then try to access http://www.google.ca (or any other non-https page).  Depending on the browser (Firefox, Internet Explorer), I get various messages to the effect that the webpage is not responding.  Using the Windows troubleshooter, I get the explanation that the primary domain name server can't be accessed.  Some more web searching yields suggestions to reset TCP/IP.  I found [this microsoft page on how](http://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/299357/how-to-reset-tcp-ip-by-using-the-netshell-utility#letmefixitmyselfalways).  Thereafter, however, rebooting doesn't solve the problem.

What else can I try?  In case it matters, I get the following ipconfig details (using a cygwin bash shell opened under an administrator acount).  I've changed the Physical Address fields, but where they matched in the actual output, I ensured that they match below.

```
$ipconfig /all

Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : XXXXX
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No


Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Broadcom 802.11n Network Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : XX-XX-XX-XX-XX-XX
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.255.108(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : August-06-18 8:45:37 PM
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : August-06-18 9:30:37 PM
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.255.254
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.255.254
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 8.8.8.8
                                       8.8.4.4
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

Following up on the comments:

- Pinging 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4, and 1.1.1.1 from a Cygwin bash shell (as administrator) generates the message "Destination net unreachable".
- Entering 172.217.194.94 into the browser address bar (google.ca's IP address) yields the same non-responsiveness as trying to access the internet in general, described in the original posting of the question
- What seemed to have solved the problem is Appleoddity's suggestion to enable automatic detection of DNS, which I will post as the answer

Comment: Can you ping 8.8.8.8 normally. Try to browser 172.217.194.94(the Ip of www.google.ca). disable other adapter to have try, all other wireless adapter or wired adapter.

Comment: google always enforces https. have you simply tried pinging 8.8.8.8 or 1.1.1.1 (non google)? please update your question accordingly.

Comment: You have google dns servers configured. Have you changed your tcp/ip settings from detect automatically, to a static DNS instead? Make sure it is set to obtain automatically so it is using the DNS servers the WiFi network expects you to use.

Comment: I'm going to have to do these next time I'm at McDonalds with the laptop.  I apologize for the fact that this might be a long cycle of testing, as the problem is a long-drawn one extending over years.  I just got tired of it the last time I was there, and decided to make a concerted effort to sleuth it down.  Thanks.for your patience.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Appleoddity's suggestion, I found my way to enabling automatic detection of DNS for IPv4, which solved the problem:
[Images of navigating GUI panels to enable auto detect of DNS for IPv4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JO6kp.png)

Interesting to see that I am [not the only person](http://sqwabb.wordpress.com/2016/11/14/the-mystery-of-the-windows-10-laptop-that-couldnt-connect-to-wi-fi) to have encountered this.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are not connecting the McDonald's WiFi correctly so you can check here how to connect **[McDonald's WiFi](https://mcdonaldsfaq.com/mcdonalds-free-wifi/)** to your device.